# stack command not found after installing haskell-platform for windows

Tags: haskell-stack, haskell-platform

Yesterday I followed the installation instructions for haskell-platform on the official haskell website https://www.haskell.org/platform/

Now I tried to use stack, but I only got `command not found` as output.
In the environment variables an the path variables, there no reference to stack to be found.
Also, in the chocolatey installation location there is no stack.exe.

Where can i find the stack installation included in haskell-platform?

Answer (score 1):

I just got hit by the same thing. My guess is it's a bug, given the packages [aren't in the nuspec](https://github.com/Mistuke/HaskellDevChoco/blob/master/nightly/haskell-dev/haskell-dev.nuspec). I've just [raised an issue](https://github.com/Mistuke/HaskellDevChoco/issues/2). At best there is a discrepancy between the package and the documentation.